# Quartz.NET не работает вместе с Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, quartz

Если в классе **OrderTime** создам конструктор c базой, то метод **Execute** перестает работать. Кто знает как решить эту проблему? Может можно реализовать это как то по другому. В интернете я не смог найти решение. Помогите пожалуйста.
Класс `OrderTime`

```
public class OrderTime : IJob
    {
        AppDBContent appDBContent;
        public OrderTime(AppDBContent appDBContent)
        {
            this.appDBContent = appDBContent;
        }
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var order = appDBContent.Order.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 52);
            if (order != null)
            {
                order.Mail = "admin";
            }
            appDBContent.Order.Update(order);
            appDBContent.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Класс базы данных `AppDBContent`

```
public class AppDBContent : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {

        public AppDBContent(DbContextOptions<AppDBContent> options) : base(options)
        {
            //Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public override DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Сategories> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BookItems> LibraryBookItem { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetail { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Возможно вам поможет этот пакет https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html

Comment: @Exploding Kitten Я нашел проблему и изменил вопрос

Comment: а в чем проблема/ошибка сейчас? не запускается job?

Comment: @Exploding Kitten Если уберу `AppDBContent appDBContent;
        public OrderTime(AppDBContent appDBContent)
        {
            this.appDBContent = appDBContent;
        }`, и в методе Execute заменю код, например как раньше было на вывод времени, все работает. Создаю конструктор и все перестает работать. Ни каких ошибок не выходит, просто не выводится

Comment: Поставьте точку останова на строку `var order = appDBContent.Order.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 52);` и проверьте отладчиком работу метода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему с созданием `Job` у которой нет дефолтного конструктора, а есть некая зависимость, например на `DbContext`, можно решить при помощи пакета: `Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, если вы используете встроенный контейнер в `ASP.NET Core`.

В `Startup.cs` нужно будет добавить, примерно такой код:

```cs
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    // при помощи этого метода Job резолвится через контейнер,
    // а не создаваться через встроенную фабрику Quartz,
    // которая требует пустой конструктор
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();

    q.AddJob<OrderTime>(options =>
    {
        options.WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .Build();
    });

    q.AddTrigger(options =>
    {
        options.ForJob("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x =>
                x.WithIntervalInSeconds(2)
                    .RepeatForever());
    });
});

services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
{
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

[Документация](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html)

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает, как я хотел!